# Issue of the Flash where Max Mercury's love interest dies

Tags: story-identification, dc, comics, the-flash

I am looking for a scan, or at least the issue number for an issue of *The Flash* from the mid-late 90s. I recall it as possibly the conclusion to a story arc.

Anyway, as the police are handcuffing the villain at the end of the issue, the Flash, Max Mercury and maybe another character are talking and the villain takes a cop's gun and shoots. There is a page or two of the villain shooting in slow motion as Max explains that people have a misconception that speedsters cannot be caught by surprise as Max's love interest gets shot.

Answer (score 3):

Not *The Flash*, but one of the latest issues of the 90s *Impulse* run; more precisely, issue #75 (2001), which was the finale of the "Dark Tomorrow" arc.

While Bart and his friend Carol are in the future to settle the mess it has became, Bart's future self describes how Max and his daughter Helen (not his love interest) were handing a villain to the police, when said villain took advantage of an unfocused cop and began shooting. Max caught most of the bullets, but when he saw Helen being targeted at point blank, he froze.

> Sometimes people forget. That despite all of our speed, we're still human beings. We still can be startled or stunned or shocked. We can still be taken by surprise.

Later in the issue, Bart changes that past and the scene is told from Max's perspective. Below are the two versions.

[image: Helen gets shot as Max is frozen by shock]